# How to Write Json Parsing Service class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Im working on JSON Parsing, I have implemented JSON Service class. But it will not take the URL String.

**ServiceAPI.h**

```
typedef enum
{
SCServiceAPITypeRegistration = 0,
SCServiceAPITypeLogin
}SCServiceAPIType;

typedef void (^ SCApiRequestCompletionHandler) (BOOL success , NSDictionary *responseDict);

@interface SCServiceAPI : NSObject
{
SCApiRequestCompletionHandler    completionHandler;
 }

@property (nonatomic , assign) SCServiceAPIType serviceType;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSData     *imageData;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSData     *videoData;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSData     *videoImageData;

- (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(SCServiceAPIType)apiType
             requestApiDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
          completionHandler:(SCApiRequestCompletionHandler)handler;

@end
```

**ServiceAPI.m**

```
   #define BASE_URL =  @"https://dev.selltis.com/webservice/selltismobileservice.svc/"   


   @implementation SCServiceAPI
   - (void)sendAsynchronousRequest : (SCServiceAPIType )apiType requestApiDict: (NSDictionary *)dict completionHandler: (SCApiRequestCompletionHandler )handler
  {
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self requestWithType:apiType withRequestData:dict] queue:[[SCGlobalDataHandler globalDataHandler] getGlobalQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (!connectionError)
    {
        NSError *err;
        NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

        NSLog(@"Response object is %@",responseObject);

        if (err) {
            handler(NO,responseObject); // if some coonnection error occured
        }
        else if ([[responseObject allKeys] containsObject:@"status"]) {

            if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 200) {
                handler(YES,responseObject);
            }
            else {
                handler(NO,responseObject);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        handler(NO,@{@"message":@"The network connection was lost"});
    }
}];
}


 - (NSURLRequest *)requestWithType:(SCServiceAPIType )serviceType withRequestData:(NSDictionary* )data
  {
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[self urlForType:serviceType] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
switch (serviceType) {
    case SCServiceAPITypeRegistration:
    case SCServiceAPITypeLogin:
    {
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        return request;
     }
        break;
}
return request;
}

- (NSURL *)urlForType : (SCServiceAPIType )apiType
{
switch (apiType)
{
    case SCServiceAPITypeRegistration:
    {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,@"registration api"]];        }
        break;
    case SCServiceAPITypeLogin: {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"base api",@"registration api"]];
    }
}
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)loginAPI {
SCServiceAPI *serviceAPI = [[SCServiceAPI alloc] init];
// starts indicator
NSDictionary *dictRequest = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.selltis.com/webservice/selltismobileservice.svc/GetDataBrowse?sUser=$$$$&sPassword=$$$$$&filename=CN&filter=LNK_RELATED_US=f01ee6a6-3bb4-4306-5553-a43a00c3c869 AND CHK_ACTIVEFIELD=1&sortorder=SYS_NAME&field=GID_ID,TXT_NAMELAST,TXT_NAMEFIRST,LNK_RELATED_CO%%TXT_COMPANYNAME,TXT_CITYBUSINESS,TXT_STATEBUSINESS&topRecord=&pageSize=100&iLinksTop=1&sAppversion=1.0.0&sAppdeviceName=<UIDevice: 0x7f9900d08530>"]];
[serviceAPI sendAsynchronousRequest:SCServiceAPITypeLogin requestApiDict:dictRequest completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseDict) {
    if (success) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // handle success
            NSLog(@"%@",responseDict);
        });
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // handle failure

        });
    }
}];
}
```

NSDictionary dictRequest is not taking the URL String. Every time I send the string using GET Method, it's not working. 
Can you help me writing a Json Parsing Service class?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The good news is, you are almost there.

<s>The bad news - `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]` doesn't work that way. It is used to load a `*.plist` file from disk. More can be read here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:</s>

This method can actually be used to obtain contents of URL, but the response need to be in `plist` format. You mentioned JSON in your question, so I assume that the response is in JSON format.

As to your immediate problem - you don't need this dictionary at all. When you are making a `GET` request, all your parameters are passed in the query. So there is no need to add body data to this request. Actually the `NSURL` object you are passing to the `NSDictionary` initializer should be passed to the `NSMutableURLRequest` initializer in `ServiceAPI.m`

---

There is also problem in your `- (NSURL *)urlForType : (SCServiceAPIType )apiType;` method. The strings you pass to `NSURL` initializer are not valid URLs, and the docs state that if it is not valid, then the initializer returns `nil` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:)

To get a working sample, replace this line:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[self urlForType:serviceType] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
```

with these two lines:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your extremely long URL here"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
```

Comment: I replaced dictionary with NSURLRequest. put the sample www.google.com working, but my URL is not taking my string. always showing nil value.